# Mount PogoPlug Drive on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I have a PogoPlug with 2 drives attached.  I want to mount one of them on my Mac.  I can use the PogoPlug software, but it mounts all drives. All i have is the IP Address and the name of the drive.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to make my 2 hd/SATA Seagates work with Pogoplug and OSX 10.8.2. First, I purchased a dual docking station from Fry's for $30. I placed the HD's in the Dock (follow the instructions for the installation and the recommended settings of your Docking Station) and via USB directly to my MBP. Using DISK UTILITY, I formatted the OSX Hard Drives as follows, and for Windows compatibility I formatted the other drive in Windows 7 as follows (please note that I have a virtual machine - *Parallels Desktop 7* - that runs Windows 7): 
My first HD I formatted as MAC OSX Extended (encrypted) *encryption optional*.
The second HD formatted with  NTFS.
I then did my system backups to the drives respective to their format (i.e.. Windows backed up to the NTFS, and OSX backed up to MAC OS Extended Journaled).
When both backups were complete, I unplugged the dock and plugged the Docking station via USB into my Pogoplug.
Then I set up my Pogoplug via their website.
I then downloaded the companion software from pogoplug and installed: http://pogoplug.com/downloadbackupinfo?platform=mac

I am able to access my pogoplug using OSX 10.8.2 or Windows from any device.

Answer (score 0):

Also, go to Disk Utility and Unmount whatever drive you don't want mounted thru your Mac. If you are in a remote location you can disable any drive with the Pogoplug web application.